# Finding the global global extrema of a given function on $\{x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+2z^2\leq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Let $K=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|\,x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+2z^2\leq 1\}$. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},\,(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+e^{-y^2}+4z^2$. Find the global extrema of $F$ on K.

---

I've first examined the interior of $K$ and found out that $(0,0,0)$ is a critical point. After that, I've considered the boundary and tried to use Lagrangian multipliers by setting $\tilde{F}(x,y,z,\lambda):=F(x,y,z)-\lambda(x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+2z^2-1)$ and looking for extrema of $\tilde{F}$ but it seems as though that things get very complicated from there on and I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: I'ld substitute $4z^2=2-2x^2-y^2$ in $F$. That will give $x=y=0$ and $z=\pm\sqrt2/2$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thank you, I'd tried something very similar but didn't arrive at a solution for $z$. May I ask how you did that?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What's more, I don't even have your values for $x$, since I've got $x=\lambda x$ and $z=\frac{\lambda}{2}z$ which leaves multiple possibilities for $x$ and $z$ in the case that $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Well, $4z^2=2-2x^2-y^2=2$, thus $z=\pm\sqrt2/2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe But for that you would need $x=0$, my solution, however, is that $x=\lambda x$ and I haven't been able to simplify this so far. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: I didn't use Lagrange, I've just substituted $4z^2=2-2x^2-y^2$ in $F$ to get $e^{-y^2}-x^2-y^2+2$ and calculated the extrema of that function.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Okay, thank you very much for the help, I understand it now.